# Why is Svelte not re-triggering a function and/or rerendering when some variable changes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, events, svelte, sveltekit

I'm relatively new to Svelte and I understand some basic concepts. I know that it's reactive on assignment. But I can't seem to figure out why exactly this doesn't work. Here's a little demo snippet which is a feature of a much larger app:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  let selectedId!: number;

  // Imagine if this has a lot more conditions inside.
  const isSelected = (id: number): boolean => {
    return id === selectedId;
  }

  const selectId = (id: number) => {
    selectedId = id;
  }
</script>

<div>
  {#each ids as id}
    <button type="button" class:selected={isSelected(id)} on:click={() => selectId(id)}>{id}</button>
  {/each}
</div>

<style>
  .selected {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

For some reason, `isSelected` is triggered only once (on initial load). In other words, when clicking buttons, nothing happens.

I think I'm missing some core Svelte concept here. If yes, how can I fix this in a Svelte way?

Thanks in advance.

I would expect that `isSelected` is trigger on every button click, since it updates the `selectedId`.

Also, a solution

```
<button type="button" class:selected={selectedId === id} on:click={() => selectId(id)}>{id}</button>
```

is *not* a solution for me, because in reality, `isSelected` has much more to it.

Comment: Axtually yes, thank you so much! I really feel stupid for not finding this answer before asking the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add dollar sign "$" to create reactive statement:

```
<script lang="ts">
  const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  let selectedId!: number;

  // Imagine if this has a lot more conditions inside.
  $: isSelected = (id: number): boolean => {
    return id === selectedId;
  }

  const selectId = (id: number) => {
    selectedId = id;
  }
</script>

<div>
  {#each ids as id}
    <button type="button" class:selected={isSelected(id)} on:click={() => selectId(id)}>{id}</button>
  {/each}
</div>

<style>
  .selected {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I will probably go with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

> I would expect that isSelected is trigger on every button click, since it updates the selectedId.

That's where you make an incorrect assumption. `class:selected={isSelected(id)}` will only update (and force a rerender) when `id` changes.

You can trick Svelte into rerendering by simply changing that to `class:selected={isSelected(id, selectedId)}` and change the function signature to `const isSelected = (id: number, _selectedId: number): boolean => { ... }` and discard `_selectedId` being passed (or use it instead of the global, both work).

[Demo REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2cc28eadc446482080c2b0b0a31e4b21?version=3.55.1)

Edit: I *do* understand that your real use case is more complex, but you just have to pass *one* of the multiple params that are updated to trigger a rerender. The choice of that param is unimportant as you can discard it (its sole purpose being to force an update).

Comment: To be honest, I actually started with what you wrote, but since there's probably can be a lot of calls of this and similar functions, I wanted to avoid passing an extra param. Thank you so much for the explanation.

Comment: You're welcome! I do understand that the reactive statement approach might look more elegant/practical. A caveat though, a new assignment to any script-scoped variables within the body of the function will have the ability to trigger a rerender. This might suit your use case, or it might not. If not, or if you want more control over what conditions trigger a rerender, consider using an intermediate variable that combines the values you want to trigger upon using logical operators that fit your use case. This might also make your code (and your intent!) easier to read.

Comment: Do you maybe have an example of "intermediate variable that combines the values you want to trigger"? I'd really like to give it a try. Maybe I'll like it.

Answer (score 0):

Svelte looks at `class:selected={isSelected(id)}` and sees `isSelected` and `id` and sets up invalidation behavior for when of those changes.

It doesn't see the `selectedId` as this is hidden from svelte inside the `isSelected` function.

To solve this, you can:

- Add the `selectedId` as parameter to the `isSelected` function
- Inline the behavior:
  `class:selected={id === selectedId}`

In this case I recommend the latter.